# Mac + jni + java

Tags: java, macos, sdk, java-native-interface

A little background:
I have a java application that needs to talk to a third party hardware on mac. They have given me the sdk but it is not in Java. So I am trying to make jnilib that will act as a bridge between my java application and the SDK.

The issue:
I have made a small sample jnilib that talks to the SDK but when I try to use it in my java program I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/john.doe/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/Lesson13_Jni_Smart7/bin/libSmartTest7.jnilib:  Library not loaded: build/Release/SMARTResponseSDK.framework/Versions/A/SMARTResponseSDK  Referenced from: /Users/john.doe/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/Lesson13_Jni_Smart7/bin/libSmartTest7.jnilib      
Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1742)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at com.learning.lesson13.JniSmart7.<clinit>(JniSmart7.java:6)
```

From the error it looks like my `libSmartTest7.jnilib` is looking for the library `SMARTResponseSDK`.

What I have tried
I know where the library `SMARTResponseSDK` is on my Mac. I tried copying it over to my working folder in eclipse but I still get the error. I have tried using the `-DJava.library.path` but I still get the error.

Any ideas on what the best possible approach would be.

Comment: On OSX the library must be found within either java.library.path or the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  You should also check your library to ensure it's not using a specific absolute path for the dependent library (unless it's in a system-installed location).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I am sorry but it looks like it was my mistake. There were two "SMARTResponseSDK" libraries. looks like I used the wrong one while building my jnilib. I used the other "SMARTResponseSDK" and problem seems to have been cleared.

Comment: You might also consider Rococoa, which lets you avoid writing any native code and access the 3rd-party library directly from Java.

Comment: How do you build the jnilib ?

Comment: Hi qrtt1,

I dont exactly recall now but I use xcode(apple ide) and create a dylib and then just rename the *.dylib to *.jnilib. :-)

Comment: Well, maybe you cloud try otool to find the missed linking path and correct it by install_name_tool http://thecourtsofchaos.com/2013/09/16/how-to-copy-and-relink-binaries-on-osx/

Answer (score 1):

Once you are inside *JNI* code, it no longer matters what `java.library.path` points at.

Once you are inside *JNI* code, all you can do is to make sure library is visible to your code via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`/`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or you can dynamically load your library file from any location you like.

So, for you, I suggest to take a look here:

- dynamic loading of library in JNI - http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/
- Calling code from shared library (adapter pattern) - http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/

You can also benefit from compilation flags while building your *JNI* library and use *rpath*.