# Library not loaded error (Eclipse/Java) - works on original computer, but pushed all to git and then breaks on machines that pull

Tags: java, eclipse, git, opencv, include

I'm working on a Java project using Eclipse and git.  I use git from the command line, and Eclipse solely as an editor.
The project on github is located at: http://github.com/samheather/3JVision
On the original computer I wrote this on, everything works fine.  I pushed all to the git repository, using

```
git add .
git commit -am "message"
git push
```

then pulled on another machine.  For some reason, even though all the libraries are in the project and referenced relative to the project, I get this error:

```
Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
```

as part of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/Samuel/git/3JVision/lib/opencv/2.4.7.1/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java247.dylib:  Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib   Referenced from: /Users/Samuel/git/3JVision/lib/opencv/2.4.7.1/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java247.dylib   Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1833)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1756)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
    at vision.LocateFace.<init>(LocateFace.java:27)
    at vision.Vision.main(Vision.java:32)
```

Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong here?  Feel free to pull yourself and take a look.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Does the other machine have libopencv_core installed on it? You might be missing a developer package.

Comment: Is the JVM bit equivalent? Ie are you using a 64 bit version of java against a 32 bit library or visa versa?

Comment: @GregBurghardt the first machine where it works has OpenCV installed as a native library via homebrew, but I was under the impression that this should not be a problem as I included the whole of OpenCV including libopencv_core.dylib and libopencvcore.2.4.dylib in the eclipse project and they are visible in eclipse (at lib/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/ in the project - check out the repo on github).

Comment: @MadProgrammer - yes, both JVM's are equivalent - Java SE 6 (JVM 1.6.0_65) - both on Macs.  One Mac on 10.8, another on 10.9.

Comment: There are 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the JVM, which if the dylib is not the same bit depth, it won't load, for instance a 32bit JVM can't load a 64bit library and visa versa

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've checked this on both machines and both are running 64 bit.  Any other ideas?

Comment: *"On OSX the library must be found within either java.library.path or the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. You should also check your library to ensure it's not using a specific absolute path for the dependent library (unless it's in a system-installed location)."* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332496/mac-jni-java)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913591/library-not-loaded-image-not-found)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I don't know that this is the problem - both machines have exactly the same settings in the Environment tap of Run Configurations in Eclipse (where this path would be set).  I tried to clone the repo onto another directory on my original computer where it worked before, and it worked on there, so doesn't that indicate that the config been pushed to GitHub is correct (and this config shouldn't need to change import paths for libraries, as all machines will import by default the local directory relevant to the project right?)

Comment: Any chance someone could clone it themselves and see if it works on their machines straight off?  It's a 3D cube project where the cube responds to the movement of the head of the person infront of the computer via webcam.  Shouldn't need camera enabled to build though.